# EditText validation

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edittext which should allow 24 hour format time mean 00:00 to 23:59

**Only two checking is left**

**1.** hh should not be greater than 23 and mm should not be grater than 59 I need to check this when user is typing or moved to another edit text.

**2.** is should have only one (min and max) **:** sign

I am creating this edit text dynamically code follows

```
final EditText timeVisited = new EditText(this);
    timeVisited.setId(20);
    timeVisited.setText(Tm);
    timeVisited.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    timeVisited.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
    timeVisited.setHint("eg. 14:30 for 2:30 PM");
    timeVisited.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    timeVisited.setSingleLine(false);
    timeVisited.setLines(1);
    timeVisited.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_bg);
    customerToCatchTblRow.addView(timeVisited);// add the column to the table row here
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)timeVisited.getLayoutParams();
    params5.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
    timeVisited.setLayoutParams(params5);

    //it checks max input is 5
    int maxLength = 5;
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
    timeVisited.setFilters(FilterArray);

    //It allow only numbers and : 
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() 
    { 
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) 
        {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
            {
                if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))&& source.charAt(i) != ':') 
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        } 
    }; 

    timeVisited.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: Have you tried the time picker widget ?

Comment: yes that is not use full becoz I am using a table view and this edittext created dinamically

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to split the source variable using ':' as delimiter which will return you an array. Now check for array size, if it is bigger than 2 then the source has more than two ':' . If not, then check if array[0] is less than 23 and array[1] is less than 59.

The code should be like: (assuming source to be the variable to parse, isInt checks if a string is an integer; split splits a string based on a delimiter)

```
var arr = source.split(':');
if(arr.length>2)return false; 
if( isInt(arr[0]) && isInt(arr[1]) && arr[0]<23 && arr[1]<59)return true;
return false;
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: but source is CharSequence source

Comment: You may convert it to String by using source.toString()